# docker-compose volume behaviour

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

Using `docker-compose`, there is an inconsistency in behaviour with volumes.

I'm using `nginx:1.15-alpine`, if I mount `/var/log/nginx`, nginx has no problem creating `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, but if I mount `/var/log`, nginx cannot create `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

**Works**

```
webserver:
  image: nginx:1.15-alpine
  ports:
    - '80:80'
  volumes:
    - /mnt/fs/webserver/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - /mnt/fs/webserver/log:/var/log/nginx
```

**Does Not Work**

```
webserver:
  image: nginx:1.15-alpine
  ports:
    - '80:80'
  volumes:
    - /mnt/fs/webserver/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - /mnt/fs/webserver/log:/var/log
```

I know that it's not required to mount a directory containing no other directories, because I can successfully mount `/var/www/html` in the Wordpress container to a volume, `/var/www/html` contains sub directories.

When using the **Does Not Work** configuration, nginx has the following error:

> nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Why does mounting `/var/log/nginx` work, yet mounting `/var/log` does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an empty directory on the host and mount it to `/var/log` on the container, then `/var/log` in the container will be the host's empty directory.  If you then try to write to `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, nothing has created the intermediate `nginx` directory, and you get that "no such file or directory" error.

Either mount the volume directly on to the target directory, or create the intermediate directory in the host directory (with appropriate permissions) before launching the container:

```
mkdir /mnt/fs/webserver/log/nginx
chmod 0777 /mnt/fs/webserver/log/nginx
```

Comment: This makes sense, thank you, though it creates one more discrepancy to reconcile. It is my understanding that container directories and files will be copied into the volume [documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container), on volume creation. This happens with Wordpress `/var/www/html` and MySQL `/var/lib/mysql`. Why do nginx directores mounted at `/var/log` and `/etc/nginx` not get copied into the volume?

Comment: If you explicitly mount a host directory into a container, the contents of a `VOLUME` in the Dockerfile won't get copied in.  In any case, the [relevant Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/e3e35236b2c77e02266955c875b74bdbceb79c44/mainline/alpine/Dockerfile) doesn't declare a `VOLUME` so it's kind of moot.

Comment: Thanks for referencing `VOLUME` in the Dockerfile. I can see that `VOLUME /var/lib/mysql` is defined in [MySQL's Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/fc3e856313423dc2d6a8d74cfd6b678582090fc7/5.7/Dockerfile) and the contents of `/var/lib/mysql`do get copied into the mounted host directory. You have stated "the contents of a VOLUME in the Dockerfile won't get copied in". Do you mean, the contents don't get copied into the container because the copy is redirected to the mounted host directory, or do you mean some other subtle thing I have not picked up yet?

Answer (score 1):

```
        Works
        ----------------------------------
        webserver:
          image: nginx:1.15-alpine
          ports:
            - '80:80'
          volumes:
            - /mnt/fs/webserver/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - /mnt/fs/webserver/log:/var/log/nginx

        Does Not Work
        ----------------------------------
        webserver:
          image: nginx:1.15-alpine
          ports:
            - '80:80'
          volumes:
            - /mnt/fs/webserver/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - /mnt/fs/webserver/log:/var/log

    -------------------------------

Both Work if you given proper permission to /mnt/fs/webserver/log
Just set permission sudo chmod 777 -R /mnt/fs/webserver/log
After that try rebuilding image it works for me...

If that not work try using 
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /mnt/fs/webserver/log
or
sudo chown -R $USER:$UID /mnt/fs/webserver/log
```